# How to DECODE a string with empty space in ORACLE SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

For example there is a string "Human Resources" and I want to decode it. If I input it like that in Decode function, I get error about right parenthesis, it's because the string is split with empty space between it. How to fix that?

Comment: Please share the query that you are using.

Comment: What is an empty space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the **decode** function in oracle, It takes the input and matches with the next value,  if it matched then it results in the even next value.

So the structure of `DECODE` goes like this:

```
DECODE(input_value,
      matching_value1,
      result1,
      matching_value2,
      result2,
      ..
      ..
      matching_valuen,
      resultn,
      default_result
)
```

Here, you can skip the default value parameter to output the null value in case no matching found. maximum parameters allowed in the `DECODE` is **255** including 
`input_value`, `matching_value`, `result` and `default_result`.
In your case, You need to use **single quotes** for the string.

```
SQL> SELECT
  2      DECODE('human resource', -- INPUT PARAMETER
  3             'manager', -- MATCHING VALUE 1
  4             'N',  -- RESULT 1
  5             'human resource', -- MATCHING VALUE 2
  6             'Y', -- RESULT 2
  7             'N/A') AS OUTPT -- DEFAULT VALUE
  8  FROM
  9      DUAL;

O
-
Y

SQL>
```

Your error is reproduced as following when you don't use `single quotes` around the `human resource`

```
SQL> SELECT
  2      DECODE('human resource', -- INPUT PARAMETER
  3             'manager', -- MATCHING VALUE 1
  4             'N',  -- RESULT 1
  5             human resource, -- MATCHING VALUE 2
  6             'Y', -- RESULT 2
  7             'N/A') AS OUTPT -- DEFAULT VALUE
  8  FROM
  9      DUAL;
           human resource, -- MATCHING VALUE 2
                 *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis


SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

did you use single quote ' around the string?

```
SELECT decode('human resource', 'human resource', 'Y', 'N') FROM dual;
```